# Replace the values within lists of nested dictionaries with zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, nested

Is there any way to replace the values within a list of nested dictionaries with any 0.0 value if the length of the list of the nested dictionaries is not equal to the max length?
Input dictionary is

```
 dict1= {'canada': {'america': [1.8],
'asia': [1.75, 1.4, 2.56],
'europe': [1.86, 1.5, 1.6],
'florida': [1.3,1.2,1],
'africa': [1.27],
'brazil': [1.26]},
'norway': {'australia': [1.23, 1.27],
'africa': [1.24, 1.8, 1.8],
'brazil': [1.25, 1.9, 1.9],
'california': [1.7]}}
```

Expected Output dictionary is:

```
output_dict= {'canada': {'america': [1.8,0.0,0.0],
 'asia': [1.75, 1.4, 2.56],
 'europe': [1.86, 1.5, 1.6],
 'florida': [1.3,1.2,1],
 'africa': [1.27,0.0,0.0],
 'brazil': [1.26,0.0,0.0]},
 'norway': {'australia': [1.23, 1.27,0.0],
 'africa': [1.24, 1.8, 1.8],
 'brazil': [1.25, 1.9, 1.9],
 'california': [1.7,0.0,0.0]}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the structure of the nested dictionaries stays the same, this should do the job:

```
max_length = 3

for d in dict1.values():
    for k in d.keys():
        d[k] += [0.0] * (max_length - len(d[k]))
```

Comment: This gives me an error that the "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: @Noorulain Islam: Strange, it works for me. See here: [https://trinket.io/python3/d821025c9f](https://trinket.io/python3/d821025c9f)